# Why is std::array::size constexpr with simple types (int, double, ...) but not std::vector (GCC)?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr

The following code:

```
std::array<int, 4> arr1;
std::array<float, arr1.size()> arr2;
```

...compiles with both `gcc` and `clang` because [`std::array::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) is considered `constexpr`.

But the following does not compile with `gcc` (version 5.3.0 20151204):

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 4> arr1;
std::array<std::vector<double>, arr1.size()> arr2;
```

For me, there is no reason such code should fail to compile if the first one works but since I did not find a lot of post on this I don't know if it is a `gcc` bug or a `clang` extension?

The error from `gcc` (that I don't really understand... ):

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:46: error: call to non-constexpr function 'constexpr std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size() const [with _Tp = std::vector<int>; long unsigned int _Nm = 4ul; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
     std::array<std::vector<double>, arr1.size()> arr2;
                                              ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/array:170:7: note: 'constexpr std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size() const [with _Tp = std::vector<int>; long unsigned int _Nm = 4ul; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = long unsigned int]' is not usable as a constexpr function because:
       size() const noexcept { return _Nm; }
       ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/array:170:7: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function 'constexpr std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size() const [with _Tp = std::vector<int>; long unsigned int _Nm = 4ul; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = long unsigned int]' is not a literal type
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/array:89:12: note: 'std::array<std::vector<int>, 4ul>' is not literal because:
     struct array
            ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/array:89:12: note:   'std::array<std::vector<int>, 4ul>' has a non-trivial destructor
main.cpp:6:46: error: call to non-constexpr function 'constexpr std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size() const [with _Tp = std::vector<int>; long unsigned int _Nm = 4ul; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
     std::array<std::vector<double>, arr1.size()> arr2;
                                              ^
main.cpp:6:48: note: in template argument for type 'long unsigned int' 
     std::array<std::vector<double>, arr1.size()> arr2;
                                                ^
```

Comment: Interestingly MSVS2015 and clang both compile.  MSVS intellisense does not like it but it is accepted by the compiler.

Comment: There's `tuple_size<array<T,N>>::value` if you need a workaround :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this is a related to [CWG issue 1684](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1684). Previously, the `constexpr` requirements included:

> The class of which a `constexpr` function is a member shall be a literal type

And `std::array<std::vector<int>, 4>` is *not* a literal type, and hence its `size()` member function would not be `constexpr`. However, the new wording allows for a `constexpr` non-static member functions for non-literal types, assuming those functions meet all the other requirements of `constexpr` (which `array<T,N>::size()` clearly does).

Per the new wording, this is a gcc bug. Previously filed as [66297](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66297).